# Can I delegate line completion inside my program to the shell ($SHELL)?

Tags: python, shell, readline

The usual shells in unixoid systems have some kind of completion feature, usually known as tab completion.

Now the program I want to modify (it's written in Python 2.7) has a command `shell <command line>` much like GDB. It uses modules `readline` and `cmd` for the purpose.

What I would like to do is to employ the completion feature of the respective shell and forward the results from that into the program. I.e. when users of the program hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> after entering `shell` I'd like to "drive" the `$SHELL` to give me the completion results, for example. Is that at all possible?

NB: I noticed that the tab completion inside GDB is quite rudimentary, so I realize that what I'm asking may not be possible. But since others may come up with the same question it would still be beneficial to have it on record.